How to dynamically add form values to a new row in an HTML table?
I’m trying to dynamically add the values from a form into an HTML table. Each time the user submits the form, the values should be added as a new row in the table. However, I’m unsure how to append the new values to a new row and ensure that subsequent form submissions go to the next row.
Here’s the structure of my HTML form:
<form id="schedule-form">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
  
  <label for="program">Course:</label>
  <select id="program">
    <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
    <option value="BSHM">BSHM</option>
    <option value="BSCRIM">BSCRIM</option>
    <option value="BSED">BSED</option>
    <option value="BEED">BEED</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="subjects">Subject:</label>
  <select id="subjects"></select>
  
  <label for="room">Room:</label>
  <select id="room">
    <option value="IT Room 1">IT Room 1</option>
    <option value="IT Lab 1">IT Lab 1</option>
    <option value="IT Lab 2">IT Lab 2</option>
    <option value="IT Lab 3">IT Lab 3</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="day">Day:</label>
  <select id="day">
    <option value="MWF">MWF</option>
    <option value="TTH">TTH</option>
    <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
    <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
    <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
    <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
    <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="start-time">Start Time:</label>
  <input type="time" id="start-time">
  
  <label for="end-time">End Time:</label>
  <input type="time" id="end-time">
  
  <button type="submit">Schedule</button>
</form>

And here's the table where I want to display the scheduled classes:
<h3>Scheduled Classes</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="schedule-table">
    
  </tbody>
</table>


Here’s my current JavaScript (which is not working):
document.getElementById('schedule-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Get form values
  let name = document.querySelector('[name="Name"]').value;
  let course = document.getElementById('program').value;
  let subject = document.getElementById('subjects').value;
  let room = document.getElementById('room').value;
  let day = document.getElementById('day').value;
  let startTime = document.getElementById('start-time').value;
  let endTime = document.getElementById('end-time').value;

  // I need help figuring out how to append these values to a new table row
  // and ensure that multiple submissions add to the next row

});



Well, I'm sure THAT code is working just fine, but you haven't made any attempts at all to modify your DOM.  Show us some of that.  And you might investigate Javascript templates.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Best to create an object with the data and then write a simple function that createElement and append that to the table you want.

Create an object with the values from the form. Since you only have a table column for time, I added a String for time that takes the start time and the end time.
Write a function (function addSchedule(Object) { ... }) and call that function (addSchedule(Object)) while handing over the object as a parameter.
Create a constant that is used to create a new element: const Element = document.createElement('tr')
Iterate through the Object with a for-loop. See the MDN WebDocs Documentation
Same as step 3, create an element for the new td that is temporarily saved within a constant.
Include the value by using Element.textContent = value
Append the TD to the TR constant by using TR.appendChild(TD)
Same as step 7, append the TR to tbody



document.getElementById('schedule-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Get form values
  const DataSet = {
    name: document.querySelector('[name="Name"]').value,
    course: document.getElementById('program').value,
    subject: document.getElementById('subjects').value,
    room: document.getElementById('room').value,
    day: document.getElementById('day').value,
    time: `${document.getElementById('start-time').value} - ${document.getElementById('end-time').value}`
  }
  
  addSchedule(DataSet);
});

function addSchedule(DataSet) {
  const newTR = document.createElement('tr');
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(DataSet)) {
    const newTD = document.createElement('td');
    newTD.textContent = value;
    newTR.appendChild(newTD);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('schedule-table').appendChild(newTR);
}
<form id="schedule-form">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
  
  <label for="program">Course:</label>
  <select id="program">
    <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
    <option value="BSHM">BSHM</option>
    <option value="BSCRIM">BSCRIM</option>
    <option value="BSED">BSED</option>
    <option value="BEED">BEED</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="subjects">Subject:</label>
  <select id="subjects"></select>
  
  <label for="room">Room:</label>
  <select id="room">
    <option value="IT Room 1">IT Room 1</option>
    <option value="IT Lab 1">IT Lab 1</option>
    <option value="IT Lab 2">IT Lab 2</option>
    <option value="IT Lab 3">IT Lab 3</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="day">Day:</label>
  <select id="day">
    <option value="MWF">MWF</option>
    <option value="TTH">TTH</option>
    <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
    <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
    <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
    <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
    <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
  </select>
  
  <label for="start-time">Start Time:</label>
  <input type="time" id="start-time">
  
  <label for="end-time">End Time:</label>
  <input type="time" id="end-time">
  
  <button type="submit">Schedule</button>
</form>

<h3>Scheduled Classes</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="schedule-table">
    
  </tbody>
</table>




++, but I would create an actual array of key value pairs instead of relying on Object.entries, since order matters here and technically object keys don't have an order in JavaScript.

@HaoWu depends on the case. I see your point. I just work for a company that ensures that the browser is always up to date and actually only uses Safari and Chrome. So I know that I can use ES6 all the way and have not to deal with pre ES2015. Having an object allows for more then this case on later extensions of the application.

I agree with @tacoshy, but i will use insertRow() and insertCell() instead. Like
let dataArr = ['name', 'Course', 'Subject', 'Room', 'Day', 'Time']

function addSchedule(arr) {
    let table = document.getElementById("schedule-table")
    let newRow = table.insertRow(-1)

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let newcell = newRow.insertCell(-1)
        newcell.innerHTML = arr[i]
    }
}

